# How do I best simulate an arbitrary univariate random variate using its probability function?

Tags: r, random

In R, what's the best way to simulate an arbitrary univariate random variate if only its probability density function is available?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a (slow) implementation of the inverse cdf method when you are only given a density.

```
den<-dnorm #replace with your own density

#calculates the cdf by numerical integration
cdf<-function(x) integrate(den,-Inf,x)[[1]]

#inverts the cdf
inverse.cdf<-function(x,cdf,starting.value=0){
 lower.found<-FALSE
 lower<-starting.value
 while(!lower.found){
  if(cdf(lower)>=(x-.000001))
   lower<-lower-(lower-starting.value)^2-1
  else
   lower.found<-TRUE
 }
 upper.found<-FALSE
 upper<-starting.value
 while(!upper.found){
  if(cdf(upper)<=(x+.000001))
   upper<-upper+(upper-starting.value)^2+1
  else
   upper.found<-TRUE
 }
 uniroot(function(y) cdf(y)-x,c(lower,upper))$root
}

#generates 1000 random variables of distribution 'den'
vars<-apply(matrix(runif(1000)),1,function(x) inverse.cdf(x,cdf))
hist(vars)
```

Answer (score 6):

To clarify the "use Metropolis-Hastings" answer above:

suppose `ddist()` is your probability density function

something like:

```
n <- 10000
cand.sd <- 0.1
init <- 0
vals <- numeric(n)
vals[1] <- init 
oldprob <- 0
for (i in 2:n) {
    newval <- rnorm(1,mean=vals[i-1],sd=cand.sd)
    newprob <- ddist(newval)
    if (runif(1)<newprob/oldprob) {
        vals[i] <- newval
    } else vals[i] <- vals[i-1]
   oldprob <- newprob
}
```

Notes:

1. completely untested
2. efficiency depends on candidate distribution (i.e. value of `cand.sd`).
   For maximum efficiency, tune `cand.sd` to an acceptance rate of 25-40%
3. results will be autocorrelated ... (although I guess you could always
   `sample()` the results to scramble them, or thin)
4. may need to discard a "burn-in", if your starting value is weird

The classical approach to this problem is rejection sampling (see e.g. Press et al *Numerical Recipes*)

Answer (score 1):

Use cumulative distribution function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function

Then just use its inverse.
Check here for better picture http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

That mean: pick random number from [0,1] and set as  CDF, then check Value

It is also called quantile function.

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment but I don't have enough reputation to drop a **comment to Ben Bolker**'s answer.

I am new to Metropolis, but IMHO this code is wrong because:

a) the newval is drawn from a normal distribution whereas in other codes it is drawn from a uniform distribution; this value must be drawn from the range covered by the random number. For example, for a gaussian distribution this should be something like runif(1, -5, +5).

b) the prob value must be updated only if acceptance.

Hope this help and hope that someone with reputation could correct this answer (especially mine if I am wrong).

```
# the distribution 
ddist <- dnorm
# number of random number
n <- 100000
# the center of the range is taken as init
init <- 0
# the following should go into a function
vals <- numeric(n)
vals[1] <- init 
oldprob <- 0
for (i in 2:n) {
  newval <- runif(1, -5, +5)
  newprob <- ddist(newval)
  if (runif(1) < newprob/oldprob) {
    vals[i] <- newval
    oldprob <- newprob
  } else vals[i] <- vals[i-1]
}
# Final view
hist(vals, breaks = 100)
# and comparison
hist(rnorm(length(vals)), breaks = 100)
```