# Generating random sample from the quantiles of unknown density in R

Tags: r

How can I generate random sample data from the quantiles of the unknown density `f(x)` for `x` between `0` and `4` in R?

```
     f = function(x) ((x-1)^2) * exp(-(x^3/3-2*x^2/2+x))
```

Comment: 1. Please share what you've tried so far.  2. your function takes a variable `x` but uses the variable `t` (which is a bad variable name since it is the `transpose` function.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I do ot know how to generate sample.

Comment: I do not understand and I bet I am not alone... Please clarify what this is supposed to mean.

Comment: Is [this](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1594121/) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly (??) you want to generate random samples with the distribution whose density function is given by `f(x)`. One way to do this is to generate a random sample from a uniform distribution, `U[0,1]`, and then transform this sample to your density. This is done using the inverse cdf of `f`, a methodology which has been described before, [here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1594121/).

So, let

```
f(x)     = your density function, 
F(x)     = cdf of f(x), and 
F.inv(y) = inverse cdf of f(x).
```

In R code:

```
f <- function(x) {((x-1)^2) * exp(-(x^3/3-2*x^2/2+x))}
F <- function(x) {integrate(f,0,x)$value}
F <- Vectorize(F)

F.inv <- function(y){uniroot(function(x){F(x)-y},interval=c(0,10))$root}
F.inv <- Vectorize(F.inv)

x <- seq(0,5,length.out=1000)
y <- seq(0,1,length.out=1000)

par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot(x,f(x),type="l",main="f(x)")
plot(x,F(x),type="l",main="CDF of f(x)")
plot(y,F.inv(y),type="l",main="Inverse CDF of f(x)")
```

[image]

In the code above, since `f(x)` is only defined on `[0,Inf]`, we calculate `F(x)` as the integral of `f(x)` from 0 to x. Then we invert that using the `uniroot(...)` function on `F-y`. The use of `Vectorize(...)` is needed because, unlike almost all R functions, `integrate(...)` and `uniroot(...)` do not operate on vectors. You should look up the help files on these functions for more information.

Now we just generate a random sample `X` drawn from `U[0,1]` and transform it with `Z = F.inv(X)`

```
X <- runif(1000,0,1)   # random sample from U[0,1]
Z <- F.inv(X)
```

Finally, we demonstrate that `Z` is indeed distributed as `f(x)`.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(x,f(x),type="l",main="Density function")
hist(Z, breaks=20, xlim=c(0,5))
```

[image]

Comment: Is it generating data from the quantiles of density or just generating data form density?

Comment: Is [this](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1594121/) what you are looking for?

Comment: Please be careful to define the interval to apply the uniroot function, use `interval=c(0,4)` in `F.inv` function.

Answer (score 2):

Rejection sampling is easy enough:

```
   drawF <- function(n) {  
     f <- function(x) ((x-1)^2) * exp(-(x^3/3-2*x^2/2+x))
     x <- runif(n, 0 ,4)
     z <- runif(n) 
     subset(x, z < f(x)) # Rejection
   }
```

Not the most efficient but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sample` .  Generate a vector of probablities from your existing function `f`, normalized properly.  From the help page:

```
sample(x, size, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)


Arguments

x       Either a vector of one or more elements from which to choose, or a positive integer. See ‘Details.’

n    a positive number, the number of items to choose from. See ‘Details.’

size    a non-negative integer giving the number of items to choose.

replace    Should sampling be with replacement?

prob    A vector of probability weights for obtaining the elements of the vector being sampled.
```