# R draw a random number from some distribution

Tags: r, random, sampling

Suppose I know the pdf of a distribution, say f(x). In R, how to draw a random number from this distribution. Thanks.

Comment: For frequently encountered distributions (e.g. Normal) there exist commands that start with "r" (e.g. `rnorm()`) to draw from that distribution. See [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Distributions.html) for more info. Also note that packages exist that offer similar commands for other distributions.

Comment: This is not a well known distribution

Comment: I don't know why the question is downvoted, this is a very valid question

Comment: [rejection sampling](http://playingwithr.blogspot.ca/2011/06/rejection-sampling.html) is an alternative to @ECII's inverse transform sampling example below.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508400/generating-random-sample-from-the-quantiles-of-unknown-density-in-r/20509483#20509483), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23570952/simulate-from-an-arbitrary-continuous-probability-distribution/23572699#23572699), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23258482/use-inverse-cdf-to-generate-random-variable-in-r/23259123#23259123), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594121/how-do-i-best-simulate-an-arbitrary-univariate-random-variate-using-its-probabil).

Comment: @ECII It's a valid question but it's been asked many, many, many times before, in almost exactly the same words. I didn't downvote, (because I find the practice offensive) but I can understand how others might.

Comment: @jlhoward You are right. I didn't search for duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

There are several methods. One of them is [Inverse transform sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) . If you know the PDF(x) of any distribution you can calculate the `CDF(x)` (integration). The CDF is always [0,1]. You work like this:

1. Generate a random number `u` [0,1].
2. Solve for x the `CDF(x)=u`
3. `x` is a random number of the desired distribution
4. repeat.

See here for more information and R code http://blog.quantitations.com/tutorial/2012/11/20/sampling-from-an-arbitrary-density/

Answer (score 2):

For most of the distribution you have functions like (runif or rbeta) let's call it vanilla.
When you have distribution somehow linked with vanilla distribution and in fact the graph of your f(x) can lay entirely under graph of vanilla distribution you can use acceptance-rejection method.

http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/tcs27/talks/sampling.html#rejs

[image]